# I am buying a house to flip. Can I get a solar tax rebate if I add solar?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, real-estate

I am buying a house to flip.  Can I get a federal solar tax rebate if I add solar?

Comment: Other information that would be needed: is this a business? Have you the tax payer taken this credit before?

Comment: Can't this be answered in the generic?  If the tax credit is only personal and can only be claimed once, that could be explained in the answer.  It's not like we're being asked to calculate the amount of the credit and not being given necessary information.  As stated, the question is if someone could claim it at all.  This doesn't seem Too Broad to me.

Comment: I'd only suggest the OP add the state. Aren't these credits also state-specific?